# does vm_area_struct change when calling malloc?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I was reading a textbook which talks about Linux Virtual Memory Areas
[image]

we can see that a `vm_area_struct` is related to an area in virtual memory, `vm_start` and `vm_end` points to the beginning and end of the area.

We know that the kernel maintains a `brk` pointer that points to the top of the heap.
So my question is,let's say there is no available free blocks when we call `malloc` to allocate the requested memory, so in this case, `malloc` internally call `mmap` or `sbrk` to obtain the requested memory, therefore `brk` pointer will be incremented/grow, then will the heap's `vm_area_struct` change as well, for example `vm_end` will be incremented to point to latest `brk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `brk` modifies the VMAs to match the changed allocation. This happens in [`do_brk_flags`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.10/source/mm/mmap.c#L3002): after checking that the allocation is possible, and cleaning up existing VMAs, the updated `brk` results in either an existing VMA being updated (if an appropriate VMA exists), or a new VMA being created.